# Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Office 365 Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, office365

I am trying to integrate Office 365 into our ASP.NET web app, however, all the examples I have come across have said to use MVS 2013 or above, but we use MSV 2012 at the moment. I was wondering if there was any way to integrate Office 365 into our system via 2012, whether it is by REST API or other means? Any suggestions or information on the matter are greatly appreciated. Thank you.